# Android LinkedIn mobile SDK error?

Tags: android, linkedin-api

I am integrated `LinkedIn` successfully using newly released `Android Mobile SDK` and all done well using `Android Studio`, but when I generating `signed apk` is showing the below mentioned error. I heard that we have to use `debug.keystore` file otherwise this error LinkedIn sdk will return same error.
I have done that too, but the scenario was while we are generating signed apk in Android Studio it's giving `.jks file` not .`keystore file`. Please tell me the step how to generate `.keystore` file and how to configure this in `build.gradle`.

***Error:***

```
  Error={
"errorMessage": "either bundle id or package name \/ hash are invalid, unknown, malformed",
"errorCode": "UNKNOWN_ERROR"
    }
```

My gradle file look like below, and I pasted the `.jks` file inside app direction, but still while installing `signed apk` its not running giving the error as I mentioned, but it working fine when installing the app in debugging mode.

***build.gradle:***

```
allprojects {
repositories {
mavenCentral()
}
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
 compileSdkVersion 22
 buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

 defaultConfig {
 applicationId "com.myapp.hello"
 minSdkVersion 14
 targetSdkVersion 22
 versionCode 1
 versionName "1.0"
 }

  signingConfigs {
     sdkTest {
     storeFile file("secureln.jks")
     storePassword "password"
     keyAlias "secureln"
     keyPassword "password"
     }

  release {
    storeFile file("secureln.jks")
     storePassword "password"
    keyAlias "secureln"
   keyPassword "password"
  }
     }
     buildTypes {
     sdkTest {
       debuggable false
       signingConfig signingConfigs.sdkTest
        }
      release {
      debuggable false
       signingConfig signingConfigs.release
     }
       }
       }

       dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar', '*.aar'])
        compile project(':linkedin-sdk')
             }

              configurations {
                 }

               dependencies {
           compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
            compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'
               }
```

I need to any one help me please.

Comment: did you generated any key hash ?

Comment: yes.we need to generate the key hash for registering app with linked in.first off all i got the same error and it's due to that hash key.

Comment: i regenerated the key and edited in linkedin.after that i can run the app successfully in debug mode not while generate signed apk

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you have this issue only with signed APK, seems you have configured an incorrect release key hash value.

Try to check that the release key hash value of the keystore you used to sign the APK is correctly listed in the "Android Package Names and Hashes" field of your [LinkedIn application](https://www.linkedin.com/secure/developer)'s configuration as described in the [documentation](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/android-sdk):

> **Generating a release key hash value**
>
> To generate a release key hash value, use the following command:
>
> ```
> keytool -exportcert -keystore YOUR_RELEASE_KEY_PATH -alias YOUR_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
> ```
>
> **Configure the values**
>
> In the "Android Package Names and Hashes" field of your [LinkedIn
>   application](https://www.linkedin.com/secure/developer)'s configuration, provide one or more values in the
>   following comma-separated format:
>
> ```
> Android.Package.Name,Key-Hash-Value
> ```

Comment: Just saved me.awesome stuff.thanks a lot.all you said is at the best.eureka i completed LinkedIn integration finally :)

Comment: @Mattia, have you done any sample application for LinkedIn sign-in using LinkedIn sdk in eclipse?

Comment: @Mattia,now happening vice versa.signed apk is working but debugging mode isn't.?

Comment: @Stella Have you provided either debug and release key hash value as you can see in this [image](https://snap.licdn.com/microsites/content/dam/developer/global/en_US/site/img/package_hash_values.png)?

Comment: @ManishSB Sorry but i haven't used LinkedIn SDK with Eclipse

Comment: yes #Mattia i done as per mentioned in the docs.and signed apk working fine now not in debugging mode.perhaps some security issue? will work only while generate signed apk? anything like that?

Comment: I think there is something wrong in the key hash value for the debug certificate. Please note that the default password of debug certificate is `android`. Try to recalculate the hash and add to your LinkedIn application's configuration.

Comment: can u give please post an example build.gradle file with explanations?

Comment: There are two separate box for each value, how can I give comma separated?

Answer (score 6):

In SDK there is "debug.keystore" file in sample app and events app
Password of that keystore file is : android

Sign that sample or event app with that keystore file. It will solve your problem

Answer (score 3):

For debug apk I realised that I was using wrong password, for default debug keystore password is **android** , command given in docs will generate hash key for any password, so please use correct password to save time