# Linkedin Sample demo not working

Tags: android, authentication, linkedin-api

I am working to implement LinkedIn SDK into my application. I import the demo code and created the sample project on LinkedIn developer console. I also added required package name and hash. I got those two from the sample demo code. 
But after adding this two when I try to run the application it always fire the below error.

```
{
"errorMessage":"either bundle id or packagename / hash are invalid,unknown, malformed"
"errorCode":"INVALID_REQUEST"
}
```

I cross checked several time for the hash and package name because this two are parameter we have to add into console.

Answer (score 0):

Posible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29787977/android-linkedin-mobile-sdk-error) post. Problem is about your are not signing correctly the APK generated. Check your signingConfig in the **build.gradle** file.

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

apply plugin: 'android'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 17
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    signingConfigs {
        sdkTest {
            storeFile file("debug.keystore")
            storePassword "android"
            keyAlias "androiddebugkey"
            keyPassword "android"
        }

        release {
            storeFile file("debug.keystore")
            storePassword "android"
            keyAlias "androiddebugkey"
            keyPassword "android"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        sdkTest {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.sdkTest
                debuggable true

        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-    android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar', '*.aar'])
    compile project(':linkedin-sdk')
}

configurations {
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.+'
}
```