# Android app not working when used as signed apk

Tags: android, json, google-plus, apk, facebook-login

I released a Signed `APK` as mentioned in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4853011/how-to-sign-an-android-apk-file.)

When I run the project from eclipse as an Android project, Everything is going fine.

but when i use the signed `APK` it is not returning any data, also G+ login is not working.

It shows the following `person information is null`

What can be the reason for this behavior?

Why app is running properly when I run it as an eclipse project and not working when I use the `APK`.

I am generating release key using the following code:

```
keytool -exportcert -alias "knowledgeup_alias" -keystore "D:\keystore\androidfinal.jks" | "C:\Users\abc\Downloads\openssl-0.9.8e_WIN32\bin\openssl.exe" sha1 -binary | "C:\Users\abc\Downloads\openssl-0.9.8e_WIN32\bin\openssl.exe" base64
```

it is working when ever I run it from eclipse. but it doesn't when ever i use the `APK`

Ideas!

Comment: did you used to set release key in the case of facebook login?

Comment: i used this to set release key `keytool -exportcert -alias "knowledgeup_alias" -keystore "D:\keystore\androidfinal.jks" | "C:\Users\abc\Downloads\openssl-0.9.8e_WIN32\bin\openssl.exe" sha1 -binary | "C:\Users\abc\Downloads\openssl-0.9.8e_WIN32\bin\openssl.exe" base64
`

Comment: and then i added the key generated to app at developers account

Answer (score 0):

> I am not sure perhaps your facing the issue same i faced while done
>   LinkedIn integration.my app work like a charm while running it on
>   debugging  mode but when trying with the signed APK it won't.And i
>   realized that the problem arising while happen the mismatching of our
>   release key with their key that getting at the app registration
>   process.

And the link [Android LinkedIn mobile SDK error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29787977/android-linkedin-mobile-sdk-error) helped me lot.

> Give a look.It couldn't be an answer hope that will be a lead.

Comment: i signed my app as following keytool -exportcert -alias "knowledgeup_alias" -keystore "D:\keystore\androidfinal.jks" | "C:\Users\abc\Downloads\openssl-0.9.8e_WIN32\bin\openssl.exe" sha1 -binary | "C:\Users\abc\Downloads\openssl-0.9.8e_WIN32\bin\openssl.exe" base64

Comment: besides it is also not retreving any data for listviews and all

Comment: G+ login ? this is enough :)